# Remember and pass value by clicking back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using MyApp.updateHashLabel on using browser location hash to enable back/forward events which works with only one issue - it doesn't pass value. This is my html code and one of the buttons (fourth) has got onClick MyApp.updateApp with extra value which I want to pass when I click on a back button from another screen/state. So when I am clicking on second button after fourth and go back it shows my a correct screen but doesn't display the value = 6. Is there any way to put it in sessionStorage for this action? Or there may be a different solution...

```
<div class="button-bar">
   <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(1, true);" type="button">ONE</button>
   <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(2, true);" type="button">TWO</button>
   <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(3, true);" type="button">THREE</button>
   <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(4, true, 6);" type="button">FOUR</button>
</div>
<div id="hash-label">#</div>
<div id="value-label"></div>
<div id="image-placeholder"></div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
MyApp.updateApp = function (hashValue, allowAppToUpdateHash, valueID) {
    var index = parseInt(hashValue, 10);
    var imageNode = document.getElementById('image-placeholder');
    var id = parseInt(valueID, 10);
}
```

And the function of a value usage is:

```
 window.article = function (id) {
   $("#value-label").html(id);
}
```

Please see my whole code on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nzsqt06a/1/

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I check your code and I get an alert with number 6, what error do you have?

Comment: Yes but when you get back to that screen by clicking back button it shows NaN in an alert...

Comment: What is the purpose of back button in you App? Do you use it?

Comment: Just come back to the previous screen with all content...most of it dynamic and being used values like 6 in my case or whatever number is but when I click back it doesn't keep the information just shows nothing...Is there any way to keep this value somehow?

Comment: I think, if you use a navigation button "one, two, three, four" you must not use back button

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nzsqt06a/1/embedded/result/ is working fine for me

Comment: @JNF Please click on "Four" button it will alert "6", then click on "One" button and after go back (by clicking back button of your browser) - It will alert "NaN" but I want to keep the value and get the same "6" in alert message...

Answer (score 0):

you could intercept the args and store them in session storage, and recover them once the DOM is loaded again.

Comment: Hi @RDeving ,  Would you please show me how to do it on my JSfiddle? I really appreciate your help.